# Homologous paths which are not homotopic

Tags: proof-verification, examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I am new to homology and chains and such, so I am wondering whether my example is correct.

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604395/two-homologous-but-not-homotopic-loops-on-a-closed-surface-of-genus-greater-than?rq=1) question, but it seemed rather complicated, and I wanted to find a simple example without having to look at commutators and such.

> Find an example of two closed curves $v$ and $w$, which are
>     homologous (when regarded as 1-cycles), but are not homotopic.

The hint was to consider a surface, so I came up with the following.

Consider $X=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm 1\}$ and consider the loops
  $$\gamma_\pm:[0,1]\rightarrow X,\quad
    \gamma_\pm(t)=\pm(e^{2\pi it}-1).$$
  Then $\gamma_\pm$ are closed paths starting and ending at $0$ and
  not homotopic.

Furthermore, regarding $\gamma_\pm$ and 1-chains, we have
  $$(\gamma_+-\gamma_-)(t)
    =(e^{2\pi it}-1)-(e^{2\pi it}-1)
    =0.$$
  Thus $\gamma_\pm$ are homologous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do not regard them as $1$-chains, but as functions $[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb C$ and use the additive structure on $\mathbb C$ to subtract them from each other. This is not what happens in homology: You add up their equivalence class in $H_1(X)$ by checking whether they bound a sum of $2$-chains.

The following example is pretty standard. Let $X = \Sigma_2$ (a two-holed torus). Then the curve around the "belly" of $X$ is null-homologous but not null-homotopic. You can probably convince yourself that it is not null-homotopic. It is null-homologous because it bounds a torus with a disk removed, which is a sum of $2$-chains (do you see why?).

[image: The two-holed torus with the curve I mentioned]

Comment: Intuitively I understand your argument.
How would I give a formal proof for this?

Regarding the torus as $S^1\times S^1$, could the 2-chain be parametrized as $(t_1,t_2,t_3)\mapsto(e^{2\pi it_1 t_2},e^{2\pi it_1 t_3$?
why do we need a sum of 2-chains?

Comment: @PinkPanther No, you are thinking of the torus, not the two-holed torus. Moreover, what you describe, I think, is a 3-chain. 

I don't think you are expected to write down parametrisations for things, since this is overly annoying and complicated in topology.

Comment: Yes, I know the picture.
So the 2 chain covers one side of the connected sums, is that right?
I.e. one of the tori including the boundary?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but the torus including the boundary is not a single chain. It is actually the sum of a few chains. You can see this by triangulating it (again, draw a picture rather than writing down a parametrisation).

Comment: thank you very much!
I think I got it now.